# Chest does not stay open on scene switch

Tags: c#, boolean, scene

I am trying to let my chest opened during scene switches and created an AssetMenu for a BoolValue which checks if the chest is open or not. But now the chest only stays open if I select the BoolValue, switch scene and go back. But if I do not have the BoolValue selected nothing changes.

Here is my Chest Script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Chest : Interactable
{
    [Header("Contents")]
    public Item contents;
    public Inventory playerInventory;
    public bool isOpen;
    public BoolValue storedOpen;

    [Header("Signals nad Dialog")]
    public SignalSender raiseItem;
    public GameObject dialogBox;
    public Text dialogText;

    [Header("Animator")]
    private Animator anim;
    
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        isOpen = storedOpen.RuntimeValue;
        if(isOpen)
        {
            anim.SetBool("opened", true);
        }
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) && playerInRange)
        {
            if(!isOpen)
            {
                // Open the Chest
                OpenChest();
            }
            else
            {
                // Chest is already open
                ChestAlreadyOpen();
            }
        }
    }

    public void OpenChest()
    {
        dialogBox.SetActive(true);
        dialogText.text = contents.itemDescription;
        playerInventory.AddItem(contents);
        playerInventory.currentItem = contents;
        raiseItem.Raise();       
        context.Raise();
        isOpen = true;
        anim.SetBool("opened", true);
        storedOpen.RuntimeValue = isOpen;
        
    }

    public void ChestAlreadyOpen()
    {
       
         dialogBox.SetActive(false);
         raiseItem.Raise();           
        
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player") && !other.isTrigger && !isOpen)
        {
            playerInRange = true;
            context.Raise();
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player") && !other.isTrigger && !isOpen)
        {
            playerInRange = false;           
            context.Raise();
        }
    }
}
```

It inherits from Interactable:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Interactable : MonoBehaviour
{
    public bool playerInRange;
    public SignalSender context;
    
    void Start()
    {
        
    }

    
    void Update()
    {
        
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player") && !other.isTrigger)
        {
            playerInRange = true;
            context.Raise();
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D other)
    {
        if(other.CompareTag("Player") && !other.isTrigger)
        {
            playerInRange = false;           
            context.Raise();
        }
    }
}
```

and my BoolValue:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

[CreateAssetMenu]
public class BoolValue : ScriptableObject, ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    public bool initialValue;

    [HideInInspector]
    public bool RuntimeValue;

    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        RuntimeValue = initialValue;
    }

    public void OnBeforeSerialize(){}
}
```